# Why doesn't my output look like a table when the black screen is big in visual studio?

Tags: c, debugging, printf

I tried to write a certain program whose output will be printed in the form of a table: 5 numbers in each row, and straight columns in the C language in Visual Studio. The program worked properly when the black screen was small, And when he was big the columns were curved.

**my code is:**

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 10) + (i % 100 / 10) + (i % 1000 / 100) + (i / 1000) == 8)
        {
            printf("%22d| ", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adjust the formatting width so that each item output is an exact fraction of the terminal / console width. For example is the available width is `80` that will fit `4` items of total width `20` without "curving".

Comment: You're never starting a new line with this code. You just happen to get lucky that it wraps correctly at a particular terminal window size. Add a `printf("\n");` to force a new line.